# Nodejs async data duplication

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, asynchronous

I'm having some problems with one async process on nodejs.

I'm getting some data from a remote JSON and adding it in my array, this JSON have some duplicated values, and I need check if it already exists on my array before add it to avoid data duplication.

My problem is when I start the loop between the JSON values, the loop call the next value before the latest one be process be finished, so, my array is filled with duplicated data instead of maintain only one item per type.

Look my current code:

```
BookRegistration.prototype.process_new_books_list = function(data, callback) {
    var i    = 0,
        self = this;
    _.each(data, function(book) {
      i++;
      console.log('\n\n ------------------------------------------------------------ \n\n');
      console.log('BOOK: ' + book.volumeInfo.title);
      self.process_author(book, function() { console.log('in author'); });
      console.log('\n\n ------------------------------------------------------------');
      if(i == data.length) callback();
    })
  }

BookRegistration.prototype.process_author = function(book, callback) {
  if(book.volumeInfo.authors) {
    var author = { name: book.volumeInfo.authors[0].toLowerCase() };
    if(!this.in_array(this.authors, author)) {
      this.authors.push(author);
      callback();
    }
  }
}

BookRegistration.prototype.in_array = function(list, obj) {
  for(i in list) { if(list[i] === obj) return true; }
  return false;
}
```

The result is:

```
[{name: author1 }, {name: author2}, {name: author1}]
```

And I need:

```
[{name: author1 }, {name: author2}]
```

**UPDATED:**

The solution suggested by @Zub works fine with arrays, but not with sequelize and mysql database.

When I try to save my authors list on the database, the data is duplicated, because the system started to save another array element before finish to save the last one.

What is the correct pattern on this case?

My code using database is:

```
BookRegistration.prototype.process_author = function(book, callback) {
  if(book.volumeInfo.authors) {
    var author = { name: book.volumeInfo.authors[0].toLowerCase() };
    var self   = this;
    models.Author.count({ where: { name: book.volumeInfo.authors[0].toLowerCase() }}).success(function(count) {
      if(count < 1) { 
        models.Author.create(author).success(function(author) {
          console.log('SALVANDO AUTHOR');
          self.process_publisher({ book:book, author:author }, callback);
        });
      } else {
        models.Author.find({where: { name: book.volumeInfo.authors[0].toLowerCase() }}).success(function(author) {
          console.log('FIND AUTHOR');
          self.process_publisher({ book:book, author:author }, callback);
        });        
      }
    });
    // if(!this.in_array(this.authors, 'name', author)) {
    //   this.authors.push(author);
    //   console.log('AQUI NO AUTHOR');
    //   this.process_publisher(book, callback);
    // }
  }
}
```

How can I avoid data duplication in an async process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are comparing different objects and result is always `false`.

Just for experiment type in the console:

```
var obj1 = {a:1};
var obj2 = {a:1};
obj1 == obj2;    //false
```

When comparing objects (as well as arrays) it only results `true` when `obj1` links to `obj2`:

```
var obj1 = {a:1};
var obj2 = obj1;
obj1 == obj2;    //true
```

Since you create new `author` objects in each `process_author` call you always get `false` when comparing.

In your case the solution would be to compare `name` property for each book:

```
BookRegistration.prototype.in_array = function(list, obj) {
  for(i in list) { if(list[i].name === obj.name) return true; }
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT (related to your comment question):**

I would rewrite `process_new_books_list` method as follows:

```
BookRegistration.prototype.process_new_books_list = function(data, callback) {
    var i = 0,
        self = this;
    (function nextBook() {
        var book = data[i];
        if (!book) {
            callback();
            return;
        }
        self.process_author(book, function() {
            i++;
            nextBook();
        });
    })();
}
```

In this case next `process_author` is being called not immediately (like with `_.each`), but after callback is executed, so you have consequence in your program.

Not sure is this works though.

Sorry for my English, I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: Hi, it works fine, but now, I have another related problem, when I do the same process but using database, the data is duplicated. I think that it's because the latency of database process is bigger, and the loop start to process a new author before finishi process the last one. I update my question with the code using databases. Can you please have a look?